mongodb nextjs14 connection error in local
I have setup mongodb with nextjs14 using a singelton class. I am on windows but mongodb is running on ubuntu in local. The connection gets established when the laptop starts but after a few hours it breaks and does not connect until I restart the laptop. The mongo client class is enclosed.
import { MongoClient, Db, Collection, } from 'mongodb'; 
import { siteConfig } from "@/config/site"

// MongoDB URI and Database Name const MONGODB_URI =siteConfig.MONGODB_URI; const DB_NAME = siteConfig.MONGODB_DB;

class MongoDBClient { private static instance: MongoDBClient; private client: MongoClient | null = null; private db: Db | null = null;

private constructor() { this.connectToDatabase()}

// Singleton pattern to ensure a single instance of MongoDBClient public static async getInstance(): Promise<MongoDBClient> { if (!MongoDBClient.instance) { MongoDBClient.instance = new MongoDBClient(); } return MongoDBClient.instance; }

// Helper function to connect to MongoDB public async connectToDatabase(): Promise<Db | undefined> { if (this.db) { return this.db; }

try {
  
  console.log(`Attempting to connect to MongoDB at ${MONGODB_URI}`);
 
  this.client = new MongoClient(`${MONGODB_URI}/${DB_NAME}`, {
    
    maxPoolSize: 10, // Adjust based on your needs
    minPoolSize: 5,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 0, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
    directConnection: true,
    maxIdleTimeMS: 80000,
    connectTimeoutMS: 0,
    retryWrites:true,
   

  })
  //console.log(this.client)
  await this.client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to MongoDB');
  this.db = this.client.db(DB_NAME);
  return this.db;
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB:', error);
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    console.error('Error name:', error.name);
    console.error('Error message:', error.message);
    console.error('Error stack:', error.stack);
    if ('reason' in error) {
      console.error('Error reason:', (error as any).reason);
    }
  }
 
}
}

public async getCollection(collectionName: string): Promise<Collection> { if (!this.db) { throw new Error('MongoDB connection not established'); } return this.db.collection(collectionName); }

// Close the MongoDB connection public async closeDatabaseConnection(): Promise<void> { if (this.client) { await this.client.close(); this.client = null; this.db = null; } }

// New method to test the connection 
public async testConnection(): Promise<boolean> { 
try { 
const db = await this.connectToDatabase(); // Perform a simple operation to test the connection if (db) { await db.command({ ping: 1 }); return true; }
 //console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB"); return false; 
} 
catch (error) { console.error("Failed to connect to MongoDB:", error); return false; } }

}

export default MongoDBClient;

I have gone through various answers for similar problem and changed the mongo uri to 127.0.0.1 etc but it doesn't work.

A solution that started working was to use, the IP address of the local wsl instead of 127.0.0.1 in mongo uri
